# Hide/Show different links

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide, show

I have a script that works on one link on jsfiddle.

I have two links. Link one is "Link one" the other one is "Link two" you can see the code on jsfiddle =  http://jsfiddle.net/lamberta/7qGEJ/4/

It works to show and hide but i cant make it show one and other. It shows everything.

If i press Link one I want to show ".open-container-One"
And if I press Link two i just want to show "open-container-Two"

Hope you understand my issue.

jsCode:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $div = $('.test');
    var height = $div.height();
    $div.hide().css({
        height: 0
    });

    $('a').click(function() {
        if ($div.is(':visible')) {
            $div.animate({
                height: 0
            }, {
                duration: 500,
                complete: function() {
                    $div.hide();
                }
            });
        } else {
            $div.show().animate({
                height: height
            }, {
                duration: 500
            });
        }

        return false;
    });
});​
```

Comment: use eq() http://api.jquery.com/eq/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I like @adeneo's answer, I prefer this method using selectors rather than elements :

```
$(".test").hide();
$('.list a').each(function(i) {
    $(this).on("click", function() {
        $(".test").slideUp(0).eq(i).slideDown(400, function() {
            $(".close a").on("click", function() {
                $(".test").slideUp();
            }); // on click close
        }); // after slideDown (shown div)
    }); // on click link
}); // each
```

The only condition is that there should be the same number of links (list items) as the number of `div` to be shown and in the same order.

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yHrS5/)**

Comment: Thank you this was the effect i was after!

Comment: done! I'm learning :) Is there a way here to make the top links close just like the on on the bottom?

Comment: @lamberta : could you elaborate?

Comment: I tryed to add a new class and .hide to make the links on top to also close the div. see example http://jsfiddle.net/lamberta/HuGaE/7/

Answer (score 4):

Get the index from the clicked anchor, in this case that would have to be the wrapping `li`, and then use that index to select the right one in the collection of `.test` elements. No need to recreate the slideUp/Down already built into jQuery.

```
$(function() {
    var elems = $('.test').hide();

    $('a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var selEl = elems.eq($(this).closest('li').index());
        selEl.slideToggle(600);
        elems.not(selEl).slideUp(600);
    });
});​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/7qGEJ/20/)

Comment: @LotharKrause - pretty much explains it self, but I added a few lines just in case ?

Comment: @adeneo - I love it! But I think that this code is treating the "close" link like the "Main link". Here it goes a little improvement based on your answer: http://jsfiddle.net/7qGEJ/21/

Comment: damn thats fast :) Thank you for the answer! This was very helpful but i was more after the resulte that JFK made (under here) because of the slide.

Comment: OFFTOPIC: If I wana work more with this code but with another question, should i do it here or open a new thread? #Learningstackoverflow

Comment: You should open a new question if there is something else you'd like to ask, and you should accept the answer that helped you the most, like JFK's answer if that was more helpful to you than this one....... @Josep - Good eye, did'nt even notice the close links ?

Answer (score 0):

Give class to the anchor tag,

```
<a href="#" class="link1">Link 01</a>
 <a href="#" class="link2">Link 02</a>
```

give the appropriate class as id to the div tag as

```
<div id="link1" class="test">
...
...
</div>

<div id="link2" class="test">
...
...
</div>
```

Do the below change in your javascript function

```
$('a').click(function() {

         $('div.test').hide();
        var showDivClass = $(this).attr("class");
        $("#" + showDivClass).show().animate({
                height: height
            }, {
                duration: 500
            });
        $('div.test').not("#" + showDivClass).hide().animate({
                height: 0
            }, {
                duration: 500
            });

    });
```

Update and test.

Answer (score -1):

Please provide the id to anchor tag which will be same as the class you need to show/hide.
and replace the $div with the id tag