# Hide/show: cant get link to also become a close button after expanding

Tags: jquery, hide, show

I have a link at the top of page that expand a text plus a close button but I also want the link it self also behave as a close button in this jQuery code.

This is the Jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/lamberta/hqwep/

I think it's this jQuery that are way of?

```
$(".close a, .closeTop a").on("click", function() {
```

Comment: It's the freaking same thing over again, attaching one click handler inside the other one, and to make sure it fails, why not stick it in an each loop? Look at your last question to get the answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13853800/hide-show-different-links

Comment: @adeneo still couldnt solve it :( and it say "Error 404
We're truly sorry, but there is no such page." on the fiddle

Comment: The fiddle seems to have been deleted, try this one -> http://jsfiddle.net/hqwep/1/

Comment: @adeneo ah thanx now it works i just made the same script over again with the other class, -> http://jsfiddle.net/lamberta/FjTd7/1/ Thank you!

Comment: You can just join the selectors, like -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/FjTd7/2/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**Working DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4zyT3/1/)

Code:

```
$(function() {
    var el = $('.test').hide();

    $('.closeTop a, .close a').click(function(e) {
        var currInd = el.eq($(this).closest('li').index());
        currInd.stop().slideToggle(400);
        el.not(currInd).stop().slideUp(400);
        return false;
    });
});​
```